# Toolbar not shown

Tags: extjs, toolbar, viewport

i have a viewport with border layout. I use, the north, center and south panels.
In the north panel i want to show a Toolbar. My toolbar definition is:

```
 Ext.define('AM.view.ui.Toolbar',{
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.wtToolbar',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.items = [
            {text: 'Aplicación'},
            {text: 'Gestión'},
            {text: 'Automatización'}
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And the viewport:

```
var tbar = Ext.create('AM.view.ui.Toolbar',{});
console.log(tbar);
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
    layout: 'border',
    items:[
        {region: 'north', item: tbar},
        {region: 'center', html: 'Centro'},
        {region: 'south', html: 'Sur'}
    ]
});
```

In Firebug the instance of Toolbar is shown. But, not appear in the north panel.
Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no config param `item`, you need to use `items`.  You can set this as an array, or as a single object.

However, if your `north` region is only there for the toolbar, I would suggest adding it to the `center` region as a `dockedItem`.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.AbstractPanel-cfg-dockedItems